# JDBI failure case

Tags: java, sql, jdbi

I am looking at some examples of using the JDBI library for Java database access.

One such example is as follows....

```
List<String> names = mJdbi.withHandle(handle ->
    handle.createQuery("select name from test_table")
          .mapTo(String.class)
          .list());
```

I am confused as to what happens when this call fails. For example, what if there is no table called test_table. What should I expect the outcome of this code to be in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what should you expect if any call fails in java? Maybe an Exception?

Be happy that jdbi unburdens you from dealing with `SQLException` directly. Here is what you will be facing https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/JdbiException.html (or ady subclass thereof, probably `StatementException` in your case)

On a side note: it is <5 minutes of work setting up a project with in-mem db to try it out...